# Where is a ResourceObject?

Tags: resourceobject

From the Wolfram Data Repository, I copy the expression

```
ResourceObject["General Topology EntityStore"]
```

into my notebook and evaluate it.

Now *where* is that resource? Is it "in" my notebook? is it in some (local) paclet?

In other words, what exactly has happened when I evaluate that expression? By expanding the output from evaluating that expression I see:

[image: Expanded output from evaluating a ResourceObject expression.]

How does Mathematica know about this resource? Did something download, and if so, to where?

(This is related to: [How create & use local copies of Wolfram Data Repository resources?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/194207/how-create-use-local-copies-of-wolfram-data-repository-resources) )

Comment: I believe the metadata has downloaded - actually getting the data would be `ResourceData` instead of `ResourceObject`.

Comment: @CarlLange: Downloaded to where -- into the notebook? into some subdirectory of `$UserBaseDirectory` (and if so, which one)? into some temporary file in RAM?

Comment: Unfortunately, no clue. I suppose you could look at the plaintext of the notebook to see what it's doing.